# Catch the error with the callback function

Tags: javascript, throw

I wrote my middleware in order to use an external code for the management of the users account. When I'm creatin a new account I use the related function of the Manager as per following code:

```
.post(function(req,res,next){
        UsersManager.createUser(req.body.username,req.body.password,function(err){
            if(err){
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'User NOT created',
                });             
            }else{
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'User '+req.body.username+' created',
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

But I'm not able to catch the error when, for example, the user is already existing. My `UsersManager.createUser` code is the following:

```
createUser: function(username,password,callback){
        var new_user = new User({
            username: username,
            password: password
        });
        User.findOne({username:username},function(err,user){
            if(!user) new_user.save(callback);
            else throw err;
        });

    }
```

The Error is:

> Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (null)

How I should handle the last row `else throw err` in order to be catched by the callback? What is your opinion about my structure of the code in order to handle the user management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using the following code:

```
createUser: function(username,password,callback){
        var new_user = new User({
            username: username,
            password: password
        });
        User.findOne({username:username},function(err,user){
            if(!user) new_user.save(callback);
            else{
                var err = 1;
                callback(err);
            }
        });

    }
```